# Raspbian wpa_supplicant problem

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-2, wpa

My old wpa_supplicant and interfaces config not work!

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    psk="topsecret"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
iface lo inet loopback    
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**I tried enable interface or restart with this command but:**

```
sudo ifup --force wlan0
```

output message:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

**But, I fixed this overriding supplicant config on interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "MySSID"
wpa-psk "topsecret"
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Any idea? thanks

```
System:
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP 
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek RTL8188CUS
```

Comment: Try executing `sudo wpa_cli reconfigure`, then reboot

Comment: the issue was in a old raspbian version, when I tried to migrate from jessie to a new raspbian, I think that is a deprecated issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your `WPA_supplicant.conf` file.

first set your keboard to `US` (or the one you use)

it worked for me.

else try add:

```
network={
ssid="YOURSSID"
psk="YOURPASS"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

if you use an SSH client like putty.
try to write with "echo"

like this:

```
echo '
network={
ssid="YOURSSID"
psk="YOURPASS"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having a similar issue, check `dmesg`. In my case it gave the error:

```
[ 2587.167643] ieee80211 phy1:rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[ 2587.167717] rt2800usb 1-1.2:1.0: firmware: failed to load rt2870.bin (-2)
[ 2587.167737] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: error - Failed to request Firmware
```

The solution was to install `firmware-ralink`. This is probably caused because I installed Raspbian using the netinstaller. The WiFi dongle itself is a "Joy-it NET04-M" (apparently using the Ralink chipset).

Note that using `wpa-ssid` and `wpa-psk` did not solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated all stuff to the last Raspbian image.. strange problem.. closed for me. Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using a Raspberry Pi Zero W on Raspberian *Stretch*.

After spending an enormous amount of time and research into the issue - the solution was to *downgrade* to Raspberian *Jessie*.

After doing so - Wifi worked perfectly with nothing more than the wifi information placed into `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` - i.e. no messing with interfaces files or *anything* else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it trying to keep the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as simple as possible.
So I suggest to write only the options you really need:

```
network={
  ssid="<ssid>"
  psk="<password>"
}
```

*Without adding multiple networks.*

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and it appeared to be linked to an update to python3 (my /usr/bin/python link move from python2 to python3). This led to problems while installing / upgrading with apt-get.
Moved back to python2, then apt-get update and upgrade did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

REMINDER: you access the wpa_supplicant.conf file on the command line by typing: sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Below is what the default wpa_supplicant.conf file looks like for my home network:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="name-of-wifi-network"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

=============for Enterprise Network =====================

```
    network={
    ssid="name-of-wifi-network"
    priority=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    eap=PEAP
    identity="username"
    password="password"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    }
```